# How to get phone mobile data for a month in Portugal as a Canadian?

Tags: cellphones, internet, portugal

I live in Canada and will be visiting Portugal for two weeks. My current plan is with Wind Mobile, I would like to get a phone mobile access (to internet) for travelling in Portugal since I will be renting a car and would like to visit different places. What is the best option, and which companies do I need to approach? And do I need to unlock my phone?

Addition information: By best, I meant good and reliable service (across many cities in Portugal) at a decent (not necessarily cheapest) price.

Comment: Please clarify what you consider best. Cheapest plan? Highest coverage? Etc.

Comment: Decent price would exclude roaming I guess, though always an option.

Comment: Some Canadian carriers (Fido/Rogers for example) offer short term package roaming 'deals' tailored for short foreign trips. In my experience they're still very, very expensive compared to a local SIM card, but I guess still much cheaper than the nightmarish prices if you don't buy the package.

Comment: The cheapest way is buying a prepaid sim card. You can find a Vodafone stand at the Lisbon Airport, or buy in some other shop outside airport.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the best option, and which companies do I need to approach?

You can view the current tariff options on the [Prepaid-Data-Sim](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Portugal) website. MEO is currently the biggest operator, so get their SIM card for best coverage.

> And do I need to unlock my phone?

Yes, your phone would need to be unlocked to use a different operator.